# GSON serializing Location object differently between Android API 26 and API 28

Tags: android, json, gps, gson

I am having issues with the following code snippet working differently between an emulator instance running API 26 vs. one running API 28.  Here is the code snippet that I am running to convert a GPS point data object to JSON.

```
GPSPointDataFinal dataFinal;
// bunch of code to put data into dataFinal

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .serializeNulls()
        .create();

String jsonFinalData = gson.toJson(dataFinal);
```

When I run this code section in the API 26 emulator, I get the following JSON output:

```
{"gpsData":[ 
  {"elevation":0.0,"location":{ 
    mAltitude":0.0,"mBearing":122.0,"mBearingAccuracyDegrees":0.0,"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":70951742958220,"mExtras":null,"mFieldsMask":14,"mHorizontalAccuracyMeters":20.0,"mLatitude":38.9264983,"mLongitude":-77.0151,"mProvider":"fused","mSpeed":0.0,"mSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond":0.0,"mTime":1575977406000,"mVerticalAccuracyMeters":0.0},
  "newSplit":false,"pointStatus":2,"time":{
    "year":2019,"month":11,"dayOfMonth":10,"hourOfDay":6,"minute":30,"second":6}
  }
```

Note that all of the location related data is in this JSON string.  When I run the same code in the API 28 emulator, I get the folloiwng JSON output:

```
{"gpsData":[
  {"elevation":40.8,"location":{
    "mElapsedRealtimeNanos":9517448972700,"mProvider":"fused"},
  "newSplit":false,"pointStatus":2,"time":{
    "year":2019,"month":11,"dayOfMonth":10,"hourOfDay":6,"minute":32,"second":2}
  }
```

Note that none of the location data is in the JSON string.  In both cases, I have stepped through the execution of the code and confirmed that there is data in the dataFinal object prior to executing the gson.toJson(dataFinal).

When debugging, I am seeing no GSON or JSON related entries in the logcat.  Any idea what the cause of this is and how to resolve this?

For information, here are my classes:

```
public class GPSPointDataFinal {

private GregorianCalendar startTime;
private ArrayList<GPSPointData> gpsData;
private CollectGPSDataServiceStatus status;
private ArrayList<Integer> splitList;

public GregorianCalendar getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

public void setStartTime(GregorianCalendar startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

public ArrayList<GPSPointData> getGpsData() {
    return gpsData;
}

public void setGpsData(ArrayList<GPSPointData> gpsData) {
    this.gpsData = gpsData;
}

public CollectGPSDataServiceStatus getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(CollectGPSDataServiceStatus status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getSplitList() {
    return splitList;
}

public void setSplitList(ArrayList<Integer> splitList) {
    this.splitList = splitList;
}
```

}

public class GPSPointData {

```
private Location location;
private double elevation;
private GregorianCalendar time;
private int pointStatus;
private boolean newSplit;


public GPSPointData(Location location, GregorianCalendar time, int status) {
    this.location = location;
    this.elevation = elevation;
    this.time = time;
    this.pointStatus = status;
}

public GPSPointData() {
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public double getElevation() {
    return elevation;
}


public GregorianCalendar getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public void setElevation(double elevation) {
    this.elevation = elevation;
}

public void setTime(GregorianCalendar time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public int getPointStatus() {
    return pointStatus;
}

public void setPointStatus(int status) {
    this.pointStatus = status;
}

public boolean isNewSplit() {
    return newSplit;
}

public void setNewSplit(boolean newSplit) {
    this.newSplit = newSplit;
}
}
```

Comment: Which Android SDK version are you targeting?

Comment: Probably you need to enable some accesses which are enabled by default in `API 26`. Take a look at: [Android 9 (API level 28) introduces a number of changes to the Android system.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all)  and [Android background location limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#abll)

Comment: My compileSdkVersion is 28 and my targetSdkVersion is 28.

Comment: I think the issue may be that some of the members of Location are now annotated as UnsupportedAppUsage from API 28 onwards, which puts them on the blacklist if you're targeting 28+. It's very strange that they're the only two fields that appear in the generated JSON, though - I would have expected the opposite (everything except those in the JSON) or the app to crash. Anyway, I think a solution (and good practice) is to only serialise exactly what you need from the Location, rather than trying to serialise the entire instance.

Comment: Clownba0t, I ended up pulling out the specific fields I needed from the Location object into my GPSPointData object and only serialized that.  That fixed the problem... though I can't understand why part of the Location object successfully serialized.  Ohh well... thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the recommendations from Clownba0t above, the issue was resolved by pulling out the specific fields I needed from the Location object into my GPSPointData object and did not include the location object.  When converted to JSON all of the fields are now included.